# Как передать значения?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть:

```js
        var data2 = [["RU000A0JXFY6", 9.0],["RU000A0JXJS0", 26.8]];
```

Нужно получить эти значения из инпута:

```js
  var data2 = $("#test").val();
```

```html
<input type='hidden' id='test' value="[['RU000A0JXFY6', 9.0],'RU000A0JXJS0', 26.8]]">
```

Подскажите, как правильно взять значения из value?

Comment: нужно распарсить текст инпута, чтобы получить js массив?

Comment: в инпуте можно написать как угодно, главное чтобы js взял как наверху

Answer (score 1):

```js
var testValue = $("#test").val();
console.log(testValue);
testValue = testValue.replace(/'/g, '"');
console.log(testValue);
var data2 = JSON.parse(testValue);
console.log(data2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='hidden' id='test' value="[['RU000A0JXFY6', 9.0],['RU000A0JXJS0', 26.8]]">
```

Comment: @DenisBubnov, eval ест все, Но в текущем тексте, скобочки не сбалансированны

Comment: @Grundy думаю, в вопросе - опечатка

Comment: да, похоже, в первом варианте правильно написано, а в примере с инпутом - нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data2 = JSON.parse($("#test").val());
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает

Answer (score 0):

```js
  alert($('#test').val());
```

```html
<script type="" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="test" value="[['RU000A0JXFY6',9.0],['RU000A0JXJS0', 26.8]]">
```